# Пустое окно браузера при выводе таблицы из бд MySQL

Tags: mysql

Всем добрый день! Ребята,помогите ошибку найти в коде:

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost','root','2799994') or die

(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db(`web_1`, $link);
$resultat = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `alex`",$link);

$table = "<table>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultat))
      {
        $table .= "<tr>";
        $table .= "<td>".$row['Фамилия']."</td>";
        $table .= "<td>".$row['Имя']."</td>";
        $table .= "<td>".$row['Отчество']."</td>";
$table .= "<td>".$row['Позывной']."</td>";
$table .= "<td>".$row['Машина']."</td>";
$table .= "<td>".$row['Цвет']."</td>";
$table .= "<td>".$row['Гос.номер']."</td>";
$table .= "<td>".$row['Год выпуска']."</td>";
$table .= "<td>".$row['Шашка']."</td>";
$table .= "<td>".$row['Лицензия']."</td>";
        $table .= "</tr>";
       }
        $table .= "</table> ";
       echo $table;
mysql_close();
?>
```

При запуске файла,однако,появляется лишь пустой экран браузера

Comment: включите вывод ошибок.
как вариант у вас действительно пустой вывод. что в исходниках страницы есть?

Comment: Как включить вывод ошибок? Мне нужно,чтобы при нажатии на ссылку происхожил переход на страницу,на которой будет таблица,хранящаяся в базе данных. Таблица alex из бд web_1

Comment: Если при подключении правильно указывать кодировку, использовать только UTF8 то проблем не будет.

Comment: mysql_set_charset('utf8'); так везде прописывала. и при создании базы ее же указывала. все равно на странице ничего не происходит и таблица не выводится

Comment: посмотрела в логах ошибок: [Thu Jul 11 19:25:11 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice: Undefined index: \xcb\xe8\xf6\xe5\xed\xe7\xe8\xff in C:\\Program Files\\Apache Software Foundation\\Apache2.2\\htdocs\\alex\\d1.php on line 18

На скалько я понимаю,ругается на 18 строчку. Не понимаю,на что именно

Comment: поишет, что не может найти индекс на 18строке... у вас правда названия полей в таблице на русском?

если я правильно понимаю, то это вот эта строчка

    $table .= "<td>".$row['Гос.номер']."</td>";

Comment: да,на русском. Сейчас снова поменяла на английский и стали вместо букв вопросительные знаки появляться. Неужели правда в кодировке все дело?

Comment: Простите, что поменяли на английский? Вообще, лучше делать названия полей на английском, можно транслитом, просто не уверен, что Mysql будет адекватно обрабатывать русские названия. Так же может очень много проблем возникнуть при переносе на production сервер ибо настройка может даже немножко отличаться, а изза этого все будет работать не так как задумано. Речь идет именно про названия полей!

Comment: @Маргарита, э то - очень ,очень плохо,что название полей на русском. Сделайте,как сказал @thunder - на английском. Это вам не 1С.